# How to sign a PDF file in Delphi with an Smart Card Certificate

Tags: delphi, pdf, digital-signature, smartcard

First, sorry for my english, this is not my first language, but let's go:

I need to digital sign pdf documents in my software, but my client just have A3 certificates (with smart card).

The problem here is that kind of certificates can't export PFX file which are required for signature in Debenu SDK or Gnostice for example.
I've already been able to list and load the certificate using CAPICOM, but I do not know which library to use to sign the file, and how to do that without the PFX file.

It is important that the file remains PDF after the signature.

Comment: I'm unsure, what value a signature made by a program has. If there is no person verifying the content of the PDF, you won't find somebody lending you their signature card. Under the assumption, that this is a pro-forma signature not adding any kind of approval, feel free to generate a key pair by yourself and use one of the mentioned tools to sign with it.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was mean.
The subscription is controlled, each user has his / her smart card that must be connected to the user's terminal to sign the document.
The problem is just that, certificates of type A1, generate the PFX file, which is used in the cited libraries, certificates with smart card only generate .cer file and necessarily request password for authentication, I can not find an alternative to implement the second option.

Comment: Assumed, the vendor of the smart cards of your client offers a matching PKCS 11 library, a PDF program with signing capability could create a signature, but no program of your own is involved. (Actually this may be a bonus, concerning the trust that displayed text actually reflects the content to be signed).No smart card worth its money will export a PFX, since this contains the private key too, see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29425).

Comment: Asking for software library recommendations is off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. Your experiences here will be much better if you take the [tour] and read those guidelines to understand what is (and is not) proper to ask about here before posting.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm testing SecureBlackBox but I do not know if this library does the job. Anyway It seems it does.